How to set up Google Sign-In to provide server-side authentication for a static website hosted on Google Firebase?
I have deployed a static website using Firebase and set up an authenticateUser function and a hosting redirect in an attempt to (1) deny access to all site content from unauthenticated visitors, but (2) grant access to a specific group of users (Google account email addresses) through Google Sign-in. I'm asking for help troubleshooting or revising the following approach, which has not worked:

Enabled Google Sign-In in the Firebase Console.
Added the following code to <firebase project>/functions/index.js:

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.authenticateUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const idToken = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!idToken) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then(decodedToken => {
      const email = decodedToken.email;
      const authorizedEmails = ['user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com'];

      if (authorizedEmails.includes(email)) {
        res.status(200).send('Authorized');
      } else {
        res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    });
});


Added the following code to <firebase project>/firebase.json

{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "authenticateUser"
      }
    ]
  }
}

After implementing these changes, the website remains open to public access, when my desired goal is to prompt all visitors with a Google Sign-In interface, and serve content only to those on the authorizedEmails list.
There are a number of seemingly related questions, such as this one, but I've found none that solve the basic question here.

Firebase Hosting is always going to serve static content that matches the request path before any function rewrites.  From the documentation:

Priority order of Hosting responses
The different Firebase Hosting configuration options described on this
page can sometimes overlap. If there is a conflict, Hosting determines
its response using the following priority order:

Reserved namespaces that begin with a /__/* path segment
Configured redirects
Exact-match static content
Configured rewrites
Custom 404 page
Default 404 page


Note that exact-match static content is served before configured rewrites.  If the request path matches static content, your function will not execute at all.
So basically, your strategy is not going to work with Firebase Hosting.  You'll need to come up with something different entirely.  If you want to fully block the static site content from unauthorized users, you're going to have to serve that content from a function that validates the id token on every request, and not from normally deployed static content, which is impossible to protect in this way.

Thank you, Doug. Your explanation and link are helpful in understanding why this approach doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions on the best strategy to achieve the goal in the question? What function (perhaps like the one you suggest?) could achieve this with Firebase Hosting?

I gave my suggestion in the answer. Serve all the content from the function.  But you will pay for that in terms of both cost and performance.  I don't recommend protecting all static content in general unless it's absolutely necessary.

Sorry if I was unclear: I was asking for an example of a function that would "serve all the content". How I would rewrite my function to do this? And since you mentioned it, what sort of cost/performance issues this approach would incur? I'm looking at a few dozen non-concurrent users in all.

Sorry, I'm not going to write all that code.  It's a non-trivial implementation that would take time to write and test properly when fully deployed.  I'm sure you can find examples of serving an entire website through express, if that's what you're trying to do.  Then you can modify that to work with files deployed to Cloud Functions.

That's fine. I'm new to all of this, and each of your responses has mentioned additional problems with the approach. There is a lot of documentation and a lot of scenarios out there that makes it hard for a non-expert to identify the best approach, so thanks again for pointing out the shortcomings. To step back a second, my question remains how to set up Google Sign-In in front of a Firebase static content. If there is another, better approach (Google Cloud OAuth2? or...?) I'm all ears. And if there is no good way to implement this on Firebase, that would be good to know, too.

Firebase Auth was not designed to protect static content.  It merely identifies the user so that you can write additional code to determine who should be able to access what information.  Typically websites are designed so that everyone can access all static content, with only specific dynamic parts that need to be protected served from a database or some other backend that's gated by auth tokens.
